# Скрипт, запрещающий просмотр видео

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, есть такая задача: загружены видео файлы на сервер, когда пользователь нажимает ссылку на этот файл(на сайте), то в зависимости от операционки, кодеков, браузера, у некоторых эти файлы скачиваются, а у некоторых проигрыватель их открывает по сети. Мне нужно чтобы только скачивались. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что имеется обычная a href ссылка?

Comment: Да, там просто ссылки на файлы.

Answer (score 2):

Можно через .htaccess попробовать:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:avi|wmv|flv)$">
     ForceType application/octet-stream
     Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: кстати вот это интересный приём, всем спасибо за помощь!))))

Answer (score 0):

Ну так это зависит от настроек на клиенте. Где-то срабатывает воспроизведение в местном плеере, а где-то скачивание. Полагаю, это касается только глупого IE.. Специально для него можно поставить HTTP-заголовки таким образом, чтобы файлы опознавались просто как какие-то неизвестные файлы. Поставьте MIME-тип как binary/octet-stream.

Comment: да я это понимаю, на работе просто сказали про какой-то "чудо скрипт", сделаю так как вы пишите, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Хм.. не уверен, что можно сделать что-то такое скриптом... подождите ещё немного.. возможно, тут что-то ещё ответят. Хотя, поменять заголовки дело пустяковое в общем-то. Возможно, проще чем скрипт прикручивать.

Answer (score 0):

Обозреватель по MIME-типу принятого файла определяет, что с ним нужно сделать: если это HTML-документ, то он отображается как Веб-страница, а если это файл формата MPEG, то он исполняется подключаемым модулем обозревателя. Если вы хотиткачивание при этом указав MIME - то multipart/mixed. Предлагаю решение на php

```
<?php
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
if(!is_file($filename)) die("File not found");
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
header('Content-Type: multipart/mixed;');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
ob_start();
echo $content;
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Это полное безумие: вы берёте содержимое файла целиком в память, а потом подставляете в ответ. Сказано же что речь о видео, а значит - большие файлы. К тому же, почему именно multipart/mixed?

Comment: Поэтому и multipart/mixed. Чтобы по частям. Предполагается что, прочитано RFC по SMTP, для подтипа message/partial. Возможно наверное воплотить в несколько потоков. А я просто дал наводку

Comment: file_get_contents($filename) как раз и грузит всё целиком в память. Всё остальное не важно.