# Скачивание .pdf

Tags: php, html

У меня на сайте вставлены пдф файлы для скачивания. И когда нажимаю на ссылку браузер открывает файл в отдельном вкладке. Мне нужно чтоб вышло окошко -Открыть - Сохранить ... или сразу же скачивалось этот файл. Помогите с кодом

Comment: я конечно не спец в веб но думаю что можно попробовать изменить возвращаемый content type. браузер определяет его по формату файла автоматически, попробуйте установить его в что-то типа "exe-file"

Answer (score 3):

На форуме уже был подобный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18006/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#18031), посмотрите. Есть возможность реализовать то, что Вам нужно через .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
     ForceType application/octet-stream
     Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос схож также с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/20891/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E-php-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0). Решение может быть следующим:

1 Есть php-страничка с таким кодом:

```
$file_name = "files/file.pdf";
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile("{$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]}/$file_name");
```

2 В том месте, где у вас была ссылка на pdf вида `href="files/file.pdf"` теперь должна быть ссылка вида `href="download.php"`.

PS пожалуй лучше будет использовать "`header("Content-type: application/force-download");`" в качестве третей строчки.

Comment: да, но этот вариант не всегда приемлим 
+ просто эстетика, куда приятнее видеть ссылку на файл pdf, а не на download.php

Comment: .htaccess спасёт этот мир :)

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы, вариант с кучей download.php не приемлим (или сложен). Вид ссылки мало кого волнует, но тоже может влиять на восприятие (отрицательно).

Но ведь можно написать универсальный скрипт, вида download.php?file=..., в котором установить все необходимые ограничения, например отдавать только файлы, имена которых есть в какой-то таблице БД.

Хотя тут весь вопрос состоит в том, что проще - редактировать .htaccess (в случае, если не все pdf надо форсировать на скачивание) или писать такой скрипт.

Comment: Думаю выбор за Sean =), кстати в случае с .htaccess совсем необязательно форсировать на скачивание все файлы - можно добавить условие. конечно, без запросов к БД, но все же

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - запаковать его в архив, без лишней волокиты.