# Как отдать php страницу как свой код?

Tags: php

Как с помощью php можно отдать страницу 111.html (т.е. любую), как будто это код самой php страницы, т.е. не редиректом?

Answer (score 5):

Есть такая полезная директива **include**. Почитать можно [здесь](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

```
<?php
include("111.html");
....
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

echo [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)('path_to_file');

Answer (score 3):

Ну и ещё один вариант:

```
<?php
    readfile("111.html");
?>
```

Так можно заставлять скачивать файлы: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/20973/скачивание-pdf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/20973/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-pdf?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#21000)